# Using flutter_sodium with most recent flutter framework

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter sodium in a current project which I have to upgrade to the latest flutter release for fully supporting iOS 14.

After upgrading it seems like pub made some breaking changes since I get the following error when building or running pub get (or pub get upgrade):

```
Invalid plugin specification flutter_sodium.
Cannot find the `flutter.plugin.platforms` key in the `pubspec.yaml` file. An instruction to format the `pubspec.yaml` can be found here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms
```

How is it possible to add a `platform key` to a dependency? The link in the output only explains it for *plugins*